# JavaScript menu arrow issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create simple menu along with arrow function in javascript. I want that, when the user clicks the menu the arrow must turn and point down.

How can I do that?

Here is what I have so far.  As you can see the arrow does not turn down:

https://codepen.io/digitalgoed/pen/qBRjxxG

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector(".open");
const trips = document.querySelector(".trip");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".model-btn");

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trips.classList.add("show");
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  trips.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
.pricing-button {
  border: 1px solid #9dd1ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #348efe;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 25px 0;
  transition: background-color 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.pricing-button.is-featured {
  background-color: #48aaff;
  color: white;
}

.open,
.model-btn {
  border: none;
  background: darkturquoise;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trip {
  /* background: red; */
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured open"> Free trial <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
</a>
<ul class="pricing-features trip">
  <li class="pricing-features-item"> sleeps</li>
  <li class="pricing-features-item">workers for more powerful apps</li>
  <button class="model-btn">Close</button>

</ul>
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: I want to add menus are with arrow function with standard javascript code ?

Comment: @sairam - perhaps you could show some sample HTML showing the expected behaviour

Comment: i added all the code above. the issue is solved already. but where i can learn javascript for ui development? do you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some CSS and javascript code check below code

```js
const openBtn = document.querySelector(".open");
const trips = document.querySelector(".trip");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".model-btn");

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  trips.classList.add("show");
});

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openBtn.classList.add("show");
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  trips.classList.remove("show");
});
closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  openBtn.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
.pricing-button {
  border: 1px solid #9dd1ff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #348efe;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 25px 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.pricing-button i{
transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.pricing-button.is-featured {
  background-color: #48aaff;
  color: white;
}

.open,
.model-btn {
  border: none;
  background: darkturquoise;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.trip {
  /* background: red; */
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.show {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
a.pricing-button.show i {
    transform: rotate(
90deg
);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#/" class="pricing-button is-featured open"> Free trial <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right" style="font-size:18px;"></i>
</a>
<ul class="pricing-features trip">
  <li class="pricing-features-item"> sleeps</li>
  <li class="pricing-features-item">workers for more powerful apps</li>
  <button class="model-btn">Close</button>

</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks Boss,

Can i use more menus like this ?

Comment: Why you are using the listeners twice times? It's useless.

Comment: @sairam yes you can

Comment: @Engin, I am just learning curve, so i trying to create for practice, i still not find a better JavaScript coding classes online or anywhere around me. e

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon to toggle

```js
let arrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");
function convertArrow() {
arrow.classList.toggle("convert");
}
```

```css
.arrow, .arrow svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.convert {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow" onclick="convertArrow()">
  <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="451.847px" height="451.847px" viewBox="0 0 451.847 451.847" style="enable-background:new 0 0 451.847 451.847;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
      <path d="M225.923,354.706c-8.098,0-16.195-3.092-22.369-9.263L9.27,151.157c-12.359-12.359-12.359-32.397,0-44.751
        c12.354-12.354,32.388-12.354,44.748,0l171.905,171.915l171.906-171.909c12.359-12.354,32.391-12.354,44.744,0
        c12.365,12.354,12.365,32.392,0,44.751L248.292,345.449C242.115,351.621,234.018,354.706,225.923,354.706z" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate()) the arrow when the button is clicked.

```
const openBtn = document.querySelector(".open");
const openBtnArrow = document.querySelector(".open i");
const trips = document.querySelector(".trip");
const closeBtn = document.querySelector(".model-btn");

openBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    trips.classList.add("show");
    openBtnArrow.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    trips.classList.remove("show");
    openBtnArrow.style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
});
```

If you want it animated, add transition property to the icon.

```
.open i {
    transition: all 200ms;
}
```